# Using an apache wicket id with css to manipulate text

Tags: css, apache, wicket

I have the following html:

```
<span wicket:id="votevaluenotifier">
<label name="currentVoteValue" id="currentVoteValue" wicket:id="currentVoteValue" />%
</span>
```

I'm trying to style the result in CSS using:

```
.currentVoteValue
{color:#CC3300;
}
```

but no joy. I know I'm missing something obvious but what? I tried using votevaluenotifier instead of currentVoteValue but no dice.

Apologies - I'm a bit of CSS newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know wicket, but if you have

```
<label id="currentVoteValue">
```

you should style it using

```
#currentVoteValue {
    color:#CC3300;
}
```

because `#` begins an [ID selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors) and `.` a [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html)

Comment: The only thing missing is that it doesn't affect the % at the end. Oh well, appreciate the help. Really kind of you.

Comment: @user3398870 Try using `<label ... >%</label>` in order to affect `%` too.